# Connecting to mysql db via ssh with python

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I have tried solutions found on other SO questions but none of them have worked for me. I am attempting to pull data from a mysql db running on a remote server by setting up an ssh tunnel. My code is as follows:

```
server = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ('10.6.41.10', 22),
            ssh_username= 'serveruser',
            ssh_password= 'serverpw',
            remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))

server.start()
print(server.local_bind_port)

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='mysqlpw',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='mydb',
                              charset='utf8',
                              use_unicode='FALSE',
                              port = 3306)
```

However, when I run this code I receive:

```
1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have also tried adding

```
local_bind_address = ('0.0.0.0', 3306)
```

to the sshtunnel setup and instead recieved

```
Problem setting SSH Forwarder up: Couldn't open tunnel 0.0.0.0:3306 <> 127.0.0.1:3306 might be in use or destination not reachable
```

I don't fully understand the remote_bind_address and local_bind_address, so my guess is that  must be doing something wrong there. I know my username/pw/server info is correct, I am able to ssh into my server via terminal and then use

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

to successfully log into my mysql server. So what do I need to fix to get it running in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't specify `local_bind_address` in `sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder`, the local port is allocated randomly. In that case set `port=server.local_bind_port` in `mysql.connector.connect()`.

Instead, you can also set `local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', [some port which is not in use])` in `sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder`. The `sshtunnel.HandlerSSHTunnelForwarderError` ("Problem setting...") tells you that you can't use `local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 3306)`.